# RailsAdmin doesn't run callbacks in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a RailsApp with RailsAdmin running and I have a model with some callbacks defined. In the development environment RailsAdmin runs these callbacks, but not on production. The code is the same, there's no environment check or something like that. The curious thing is that it works on some models on production, but not on others. On development, it works with all models. The only difference between those models is, that I have some custom fields (string arrays to support postgres arrays and some wysiwyg fields) on the ones where it is not working.

This is the custom array definition:

`config/initializers/rails_admin_pg_arrays.rb`:

```
class RailsAdminPgStringArray < RailsAdminPgArray
  def parse_input(params)
    parsed_string = CSV.parse_line(params[name])
    params[name] = parsed_string.nil? ? [] : parsed_string.compact
  end
end
```

And this the RailsAdmin custom definition in the model:
`app/models/some_model.rb`:

```
  rails_admin do
    edit do
      configure :field_with_array, :pg_string_array

      # fields with the wysiwyg
      [
        :text_field_1,
        ...
        :text_field_n
      ].each do |rich_text_field|
        configure rich_text_field, :ck_editor
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Could you show us the code used to set the value?

Comment: The value is set via the RailsAdmin interface. Otherwise, I am not sure what you mean, sorry!

Comment: Maybe if you show us the callbacks and the rails admin configuration of a model that works an another one that does not.